# Beamer No ball Rules

Tags: rules, cricket

If batsman is out of his popping crease and fast bowler bowl ball full toss delievery (without pitching on ground)above the hip is it considered as no ball or just because he's out of his popping crease so it should be above shoulder level?

Answer (score 3):

The laws are clear. Any non-pitching delivery which would or does pass the popping crease above waist height of an upright standing striker is by definition unfair.

There is no allowance for the striker being outside the popping crease, and there is never a requirement that the ball pass the striker above shoulder height.

If the striker's end umpire determines that the ball would have dropped below waist height at the popping crease, the delivery is a ball and legal.

If it is determined otherwise, the umpire should call and signal No ball. Further, if the umpire decides such a ball to be dangerous (regardless of any protective equipment that is or may be worn) the bowler should be cautioned and warned, or if this is deliberate or repeated, the umpire may immediately suspend the bowler from bowling for the remainder of the match.

> **41.7 Bowling of dangerous and unfair non-pitching deliveries**
>
> **41.7.1** Any delivery, which passes or would have passed, without pitching, above waist height of the striker standing upright at the popping crease, is unfair. Whenever such a delivery is bowled, the umpire shall call and signal No ball.

Comment: I believe the OP may be getting confused with the 2000 code which determined that slower deliveries would have to be over shoulder height. There is the ability for the umpire to decide in the current laws that a ball above waist height is not deemed dangerous enough to warrant warnings based on certain factors as stated in https://lords-stg.azureedge.net/mediafiles/lords/media/documents/updatestolaws2ndedition_v4.pdf